# Hover and focus on JQuery autocomplete items

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I am building a JQuery `autocomplete` with a special render menu, everything works fine. But I have a problem with hover and focus on `autocomplete` items, hover works fine in Google Chrome but it does not  in IE. Focus does not work in IE nor in Google Chrome.

This is my CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete  
{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 400px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:<%=Session("COR")%>;
    border: 2px solid #658DF2;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
} 
.ui-menu-item table tr:hover td {
    background-color: #FEF693;
}
```

And here is my autocomplete render menu:

```
$(function() {
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        ul.append("<table width=100% class='clsStd'><thead><tr><th width=15%>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            self._renderItemData(ul, item );
        });
    };
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItemData = function(ul, item) {
        return this._renderItem(ul, item ).data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item );
    };
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li class='ui-menu-item'></li>")
          .append( "<table width=100% class='clsStd' border='0' style='cursor:pointer;padding:0;'><tr><td width='15%'><a>"+item.value+"</a></td>"+"<td width='85%'><a>"+item.label+"</a></td></tr></table>" )
          .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

I tried this: "`.ui-menu-item table tr:hover td, .ui-menu-item table tr:focus td`" but it does not seem to work fine!!

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Copy and paste the CSS and JavaScript here please.

Comment: Try to write css and js only for specific browsers.. this site may be helps
http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: I have already added my code!! thanks

Comment: On the contrary - _avoid_ writing CSS and JS for specific browsers. The point of libraries is so we don't have to worry about doing that...